# wrap a sprite portion outside the boundary to the other side

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am a bit new to game development. I am using Phaserjs now for my html5 game. I want to bring the portion of sprite that went outside one side of the boundary to the other side. I have gone through [image docs in Phaser](http://docs.phaser.io/Phaser.Image.html). I am not sure how to proceed. Thought of copying the portion and pasting on to the canvas but the game object references won't be same. Moreover, the copy functionality has its restrictions (copies from top left of the image).

I went through [Phaser examples](http://examples.phaser.io/). But didn't get any clue.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly, you could try this solution:

- Make a PNG that's the width of your canvas + the width of your original sprite
- Put your original sprite on either end of your png (so it would be `sprite` + `blank space` + `sprite` in your PNG
- Add it to your game just like any other sprite

Now if you move your sprite partially off-screen, its copy will move into the screen at the exact same y spot.

There may be a better solution that would work with spritesheet animation and collisions, but this seems simpler than cutting portions of images and moving them around.

Answer (score 0):

This is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m8nj4cjr/

Even though I'm new to phaser-framework, it uses canvas renderer. I hope canvas example will help you.

You need to handle two cases:

1. Sprite is partially out of canvas bounds
2. Sprite is totally out of canvas bounds

Let a sprite is moving right. If condition `sprite.x + sprite.width > canvas.width` is true, the sprite is partially out of bounds. Render portion of sprite in out of bounds at left end of canvas. `context.rect(sprite.x - canvas.width, sprite.y, sprite.width, sprite.height);`

When the sprite is totally out of right end bound `sprite.x > canvas.width`, set its position of x to 0. `sprite.x = 0`